# I don't get whats wrong with the mysql syntax

Tags: mysql, sql, database

```
    CREATE TABLE hoofdtoonder
  (
     id             INT NOT NULL,
     idondersoorten INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES `ondersoort`(`id`) NOT NULL,
  )
```

//making table but the error is with the references its on a mysql database someone please help

It says error at `FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES ondersoort(id) NOT NULL`. But I don't know what's wrong with the syntax.

Comment: **What** error do you get?

Comment: sql error  1064 :syntax error at what i stated

Comment: `FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES` are supposed to be `NOT NULL`. It is not necessary to explicitly specify `NOT NULL` at the end.

Comment: change **NOT NULL,** to **NOT NULL**

Comment: SQL Fout (1064): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES voeding(id) NOT NULL,  )' at line 4
still getting syntax error

Comment: @JoeyZhang That just isn't true. A column that has a `foreign key` on it can most certainly have `null` values, unless you have another constraint (such as `not null`) on it.

Comment: also without the not null it still gives me the error

Comment: There's no need to set the NOT NULL at all.  The column is a foreign key reference

Comment: @JamesShaver not true. A foreign key means the column can't have a **value** that isn't in the column it points to. A `null` is not value, it's the lack thereof. You can most certainly have a `null` in a foreign key column, unless you have something else in place to prevent that. See, e.g., this [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/10b9f1).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several things wrong here:

1. First, for an inline constraint, you don't need to specify `foreign key`, just `references`.
2. The `not null` clause should come before the `references` clause.
3. You have a redundant comma at the end of the last column's specification.

To put it all together:

```
CREATE TABLE hoofdtoonder (
    id             INT NOT NULL,
    idondersoorten INT NOT NULL REFERENCES `ondersoort`(`id`)     
);
```

Answer (score 0):

MySQL does not support inline foreign key references.

It's true that the SQL language allows for syntax like @Mureinik suggested:

```
idondersoorten INT NOT NULL REFERENCES `ondersoort`(`id`)
```

But you will find that MySQL parses this and ignores it. InnoDB does not support inline foreign key syntax. If you now run `SHOW CREATE TABLE hoofdtoonder`, it'll show this:

```
CREATE TABLE `hoofdtoonder` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `idondersoorten` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Where did the REFERENCES go? It was silently discarded. This is actually a beef I have with MySQL, that it recognizes some valid constraint syntax, but ignores it. It doesn't even show you a warning. It just defines the table *without* the constraint.

In MySQL, you must declare a foreign key as a table-level constraint, like this:

```
CREATE TABLE hoofdtoonder (
    id             INT NOT NULL,
    idondersoorten INT NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (idondersoorten) REFERENCES `ondersoort`(`id`)     
);
```